# ActiveRecord::Rollback doesn't seems to do a transaction rollback

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions, rollback

One day I noticed my transactions dont accept a ActiveRecord::Rollback. I have such an example:

## example

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    puts @shipment_list.status
    @shipment_list.update(shipment_list_params)
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end
puts @shipment_list.status
```

## result

```
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `shipment_lists`.* FROM `shipment_lists`  WHERE `shipment_lists`.`id` = 24121  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", "24121"]]
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
reserve
(1.3ms)  SELECT MAX(`audits`.`version`) AS max_id FROM `audits`  WHERE `audits`.`auditable_id` = 24121 AND `audits`.`auditable_type` = 'ShipmentList'
SQL (160.5ms)  INSERT INTO `audits` (`action`, `auditable_id`, `auditable_type`, `audited_changes`, `created_at`, `remote_address`, `request_uuid`, `user_id`, `user_type`, `version`) VALUES ('update', 24121, 'ShipmentList', '---\nstatus:\n- reserve\n- 2\n', '2016-07-10 12:01:55', '127.0.0.1', 'efc5b6e7-c3f9-4b4a-a0fd-67651b2eeb20', 18, 'User', 19)
SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `shipment_lists` SET `status` = 2, `updated_at` = '2016-07-10 12:01:55' WHERE `shipment_lists`.`id` = 24121
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
bill
```

Where is the mistake? I really in a trouble.

Comment: In the last line of your example, can you try `@shipment_list.reload` and `@shipment_list.status` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this has no effect

Comment: What is it that makes you think it's not doing a rollback? The log you pasted includes a `ROLLBACK`.  What's the actual problem you are observing? What are you seeing that's different from what you expect?

Comment: So, the status is changed. But I want to rollback a transaction. I want to get old status value that I had before update method.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was caused by myISAM mysql schema. Transactions rollback is not allowed.